# Mixed dates in column

Tags: python, pandas, date

Working with Pandas: I have a very large dataframe where one column (imported from many .csv and .xlsx files) has mixed dates in different formats. I manage to unify all the separators /.- but still not able to unify the dates YYYY/MM/DD and DD/MM/YYYY into one of them (not really relevant which).

**I have a column in a very large DataFrame:**

```
Date
15-11-2021
2021-11-11
2021-11-20
19-11-2021
...
```

**And I need:**

```
Date
15-11-2021
11-11-2021
20-11-2021
19-11-2021
...
```

I tried solutions from old question no. 502726 and no. 49435438 but did not work

Like this:

```
datetime.datetime.strptime(df['Date'], "%d-%m-%Y").strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
```

But gave the error: *AttributeError: type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'datetime'*

Or the function definition:

```
new_date_format='%Y-%m-%d'
old_date_format='%d-%m-%Y'
def conv_dates_series(df, col, old_date_format, new_date_format):
    df[col] = pd.to_datetime(df[col], format=old_date_format).dt.strftime(new_date_format)
    return df
```

But quickly returns error when find a unexpected correct format is seen (probably a if/then clause will help here but I do not know how to use with to_datetime(format).

Any idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `pd.to_datetime` and let Pandas infers correct format:

```
>>> pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
0   2021-11-15
1   2021-11-11
2   2021-11-20
3   2021-11-19
Name: Date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

To convert to string:

```
>>> pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).astype(str)
0   2021-11-15
1   2021-11-11
2   2021-11-20
3   2021-11-19
Name: Date, dtype: object
```

Comment: Indeed elegant, Thanks!

Comment: Since my reputation is so low, my votes do not give points. I try now again.

Comment: @GuillermoDC. In your case, you don't need to use `dt.strftime`, a simple cast like `.astype(str)` works well.

Comment: Indeed. Thanks. I would like to accept both, since both work!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the `Date` column values are strings (and assuming there aren't any weird formats like `%Y-%d-%m`), I was able to simply use `pd.Timestamp`:

```py
In [4]: df
Out[4]:
         Date
0  15-11-2021
1  2021-11-11
2  2021-11-20
3  19-11-2021

In [5]: df["Date"].apply(pd.Timestamp)
Out[5]:
0   2021-11-15
1   2021-11-11
2   2021-11-20
3   2021-11-19
Name: Date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Alternatively, you can use `pd.to_datetime(df["Date"])`.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the solution, rather simple:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```